# netCDF4ninstall not working with python3.8

Tags: netcdf4, python-3.8

I am trying to install the netCDF4 module to a conda environment that's using python3.8 using `conda install netCDF4` but am receiving the following error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found                                                                                                                                                                                   
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - netcdf4 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package pip conflicts for:
python=3.8 -> pip
netcdf4 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> pip
Package wheel conflicts for:
python=3.8 -> pip -> wheel
netcdf4 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel
Package certifi conflicts for:
python=3.8 -> pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
Package setuptools conflicts for:
netcdf4 -> setuptools
python=3.8 -> pip -> setuptools
Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
netcdf4 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
python=3.8 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
```

I need to user python3.8 to make use of another module. Does anyone know why netCDF4 might not work with python3.8?

Comment: Possible workaround: clone the repo from github and build and install it in your conda env. Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: Thank you! I've not cloned a repository before, but I guess I just follow these instructions:

https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/cloning-a-repository

Is there a specific directory that I need to clone it to?

Comment: Wait, just to make sure: you're wanting to install the [Python wrapper](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python/) for netcdf4, right? In that case, what might also work for you is to use pip. `pip install netcdf4`. If pip is installed in your conda env (it should be if Python is), that might be a good option. See [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1429) for some discussion. I usually prefer using pip for Python packages in conda envs, but it can create some confusion because you then basically have two package managers.

Comment: If you prefer to try building from scratch, yes, just follow the instructions on that page and apply them to the repo I linked above. No need for a special directory. Change into the cloned repo in a shell, make sure your target conda env is enabled and type `pip install .`.